# Pass an enum in [routerlink]: Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have the following enum:

```
export enum InternalUrls {
  Login = '/login',
  Register = '/register'
}
```

... and in my `Component`'s html I have the following:

```
<div class="forgot-phone text-right f-right">
    <a [routerLink]="InternalUrls.Register" class="text-right f-w-600"> Don't have an account? <i class="text-c-blue">Register</i></a>
</div>
```

I want to manage all my links in one place. How can I do that coz my IDE is already complaining on the above code?
i.e. `[routerLink]="InternalUrls.Register"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template can only access varibles in your component classs. If it is not a property of component's class, it won't be available in your template.
In your `.component.ts` :

```
export enum InternalUrls {
    Login = '/login',
    Register = '/register'
}
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    internalUrls = InternalUrls;
    ....
}
```

And in your template:

```
  <div class="forgot-phone text-right f-right">
      <a [routerLink]="internalUrls.Register" class="text-right f-w-600"> 
          Don't have an account? 
          <i class="text-c-blue">Register</i>
      </a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
<div class="forgot-phone text-right f-right">
  <a [routerLink]="{ value === login ? InternalUrls.Login : InternalUrls.Register}" class="text-right f-w-600"> Don't have an account? <i class="text-c-blue">Register</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: coz I want to manage my URLs in one place such that if I change in one place changes in all

Comment: @Kihats and how to do get the value ? I mean how do you know when it needs to be `register` or `login` ? If there're only 2 you can do a ternary condition inside interpollation

Comment: those two are just for illustration. It can be a long list. 
I don't want to pass the `string` since if the link is referenced in many places and probably I would want to change I'll have to change in all those places

Comment: Eudz check @shaktimaan answer. that's what I was talking about. Thanks though